# Optimization bootstrap progress bar in Symfony Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a problem with the view optimization. I need to read from the machine every minute if it is running or not and I need to show it using the bootstrap progress bar.
Now is the code:

```
{% for current in machine.Currency %}
  {% if date(current.Date) >= date(date1) and date(current.Date) <= date(date2) and date(current.Hour) >= date(hour1) and date(current.Hour)<= date(hour2) %}

    {% if current.Value < machine.Settings.workValue  %}
         <div data-machine='{{machine.Id}}' {%if current.Comment%} comment-header='{{current.Comment.Header}}' comment-body="{{current.Comment.Comment}}"{%endif %}  group-hier={{i}} data-value='{{current.Value}}' measure-date='{{current.Date}}' measure-hour='{{current.Hour}}' class="stopMachine progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-warning bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ></div>
    {% set i = i + 1 %}    
  {% else %}
    {% set i = 0 %}            
         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ></div><hr />            
     {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Currently loading 20,000 records in the database. Is there any way to optimize this view?

Comment: This is only the template code. I can not see where the 20.000 records from the database come from. Do yo mean the for-loop over machine.Currency?

Comment: Yes. Every minute there is a currency measurement and this is one record in the database. If there is a measuremet, creates a div success-bar and if not a warning-bar

Comment: Thanks. That helps understanding the issue. Can you maybe also explain how exactly you want to optimize it? Less iterations in the for-loop? Less SQL-queries? Does the page take too long to load/display or is the memory consumption too high?

Comment: I would like to create one progress bar. If there is a stop, create a warning bar. I would like fewer entries to be loaded on the site

Comment: In that case I think the easiest solution would be to group the measurements. Is it important to keep the failed/successful measurements in the order they are in? So for example with 3 measurements "success, fail, success" the progress bar should be `oxo` and with success, success, fail it's `oox`? Also, can you please outline the basic table structure and/or how the entities look. The properties needed for the view should be enough.

Comment: How can group it ? The order is important and in addition if the machine has stopped it must be possible to enter a comment, on the bar why it was stopping.

Comment: Not sure how to group it yet, but the "answer" by your colleague helps. When I find some more time I will try to come up with something.

Comment: Thank you very much . If you have any idea, please write here.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that we don't want to make 20k little divs and we need to have a possibility to write a comment for every warning bar, for example:

Let's take 10 ordered by time and date entreis. The most important information is value of the measure because it's specify the class of the bar element(success, warning).
 
1: value: 10 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:00 , machine:1
2: value: 10 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:01, machine:1
3: value: 10 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:02, machine:1
4: value: 15 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:03, machine:1
5: value: 15 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:04, machine:1
6: value: 15 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:05, machine:1
7: value: 15 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:06, machine:1
8: value: 10 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:07, machine:1
9: value: 10 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:08, machine:1
10: value: 10 , date:2018-10-10 ,hour: 14:09, machine:1

Let's make the workValue for this machine to be 11. Now it puts 10 divs

3*alert
4*success
3*alert

and we want to make them be 3 wide divs instead of 10 divs(they're grouped using javascript by attribute group-hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

So, one possible solution to optimize this, is to filter the required measurements when fetching the data from the database. In other words, your if-condition should be transformed into a query:

```
{% if date(current.Date) >= date(date1) and date(current.Date) <= date(date2) and date(current.Hour) >= date(hour1) and date(current.Hour)<= date(hour2) %}
```

is replaced with something like this inside your `CurrencyRepository`:

```
public function findCurrencyValuesByMachineByIdInTimeFrame(
    int $machineId,
    DateTime $startDate,
    DateTime $endDate,
    int $startHour,
    int $endHour
): array {
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('machine');

    return $queryBuilder
        ->where('currency.machine = :id')
        ->andWhere('currency.Date >= :startDate')
        ->andWhere('currency.Date <= :endDate')
        ->andWhere('currency.Hour >= :startHour')
        ->andWhere('currency.Hour <= :endHour')
        ->setParameters([
            'id' => $machineId,
            'startDate' => $startDate,
            'endDate' => $endDate,
            'startHour' => $startHour,
            'endHour' => $endHour,
        ])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

This assumes that Currency relates back to Machine. That way only the required currency-values will be fetched.

Comment: As a side note having separate start/end date + hour could cause problems when doing this query. Assume you search for values from last week at 9 to today at 12, with your filtering it will only return values for each data in between AND in the time from 9-12. So for example the measurements from yesterday 12:01 to today at 9 will be ignored. You should probably use one datetime value for this.